# Can I use the same app template to create and distribute the same application, with different content on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Recently I created a wallpaper application and I have a question about using the same application template for different wallpaper purpose application.

Can I use the same app template to create the same wallpaper app with different resources?

The coding is equal, but contents of app are different. Do Google Play Store allows us to use the same app template to create different apps with the same purpose?

What I mean is, I created wallpaper app which I am using for mix wallpapers. Now what I want is to know if I can use the same project to create some different wallpapers apps with different name and project name for different wallpapers.

### example:

same wallpaper app template:

1. **flowers wallpaper:** com.app.flowerwallpapers
2. **game wallpapers:** com.app.gamewallpapers
3. **more:** com.app.more

Comment: As long as the package name is different, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: While your concept may work, its best to create a "single app", that has the necessary code, then [use a resource additional file](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) with additional parts. This way, your "single app" can have more content, download-able or pay-able on per expansion, as well as gathering all downloads/votes on Google Play to that single app. Thus gaining more repputation on the store, being more likely to be shown as a good app for new users.

Comment: thanks :) it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each application on Android Play Store is assigned with an identifier which is your application's package name. This identifier is unique across whole Play Store. You define your application Id in field **applicationId** in **build.gradle**:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.wallpaper"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
 }
```

> example: same wallpaper app template
>
> 1. flowers wallpaper / com.flowerwallpapers.app
> 2. game wallpapers / com.gamewallpapers.app
> 3. more / com.more.app

As you have mentioned in your question, each app you define with different package name so there is no problem when uploading your application to Play Store. Google doesn't check app template etc ...